# DCP requirement violated when specifying constraing in cvxpy, perhaps need to rethink entire formulation of problem

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, integer-programming

This is a follow-up to an earlier [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416823/specifying-complex-constraints-in-cvxpy-yields-strict-inequalities-error/65418937?noredirect=1#comment115672258_65418937), but as I  add more complexity to the problem formulation, I realize that I need to take a step back and consider whether cvxpy is the best tool for my problem.

What I'm trying to solve: create the largest cluster of a category and company where the average values are above a particular threshold.  The trick is that if we include particular categories for a company in the cluster, in order to add another company, that company also should have high values for the same categories.  [image: Screenshot of dummy example]

I've formulated this as an integer linear optimization problem, where I've expanded out all the variables.  There are 2 main problems:

1. Constraint 8 violates the DCP rule.  Constraint 8 is intended to keep the values included in the cluster above a particular threshold.  I check this by taking the average of the non-zero variables.
2. The actual problem will require thousands of variables and constraints to be specified (there are 100 categories and >10K companies).  This makes me question whether this is the correct approach at all.

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
import cvxopt 

util = np.array([0.7, 0.95, 0.3, 2, 1.05, 2.2, 4, 1, 3])

# The variable we are solving for
dec_vars = cp.Variable(len(util), boolean = True)

tot_util = util @ dec_vars

is_zero_bucket1= cp.Variable(1, boolean = True)
is_zero_bucket2= cp.Variable(1, boolean = True)
is_zero_bucket3= cp.Variable(1, boolean = True)

is_zero_cat1 = cp.Variable(1, boolean=True)
is_zero_cat2 = cp.Variable(1, boolean=True)
is_zero_cat3 = cp.Variable(1, boolean=True)

# at least 2 categories should be included for a given company
constr1 = sum(dec_vars[0:3]) >= 2 * is_zero_bucket1
constr2 = sum(dec_vars[3:6]) >= 2 * is_zero_bucket2
constr3 = sum(dec_vars[6:9]) >= 2 * is_zero_bucket3

# at least 2 columns (companies) for a given category that's selected
constr4 = dec_vars[0] + dec_vars[3] + dec_vars[6] >= 2 * is_zero_cat1
constr5 = dec_vars[1] + dec_vars[4] + dec_vars[7] >= 2 * is_zero_cat2
constr6 = dec_vars[2] + dec_vars[5] + dec_vars[8] >= 2 * is_zero_cat3

constr7 = np.ones(len(util)) @ dec_vars >= 2

constr8 = (tot_util/cp.sum(dec_vars)) >= 1.3

cluster_problem = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(tot_util), [constr1, constr2, constr3, constr4, constr5, constr6, constr8])

cluster_problem.solve()
```

#### Update

I modified as per the suggestions.  The problem now is that the decision variables matrix itself doesn't incorporate the rules for adjacent companies / categories.  To do that, I can make the objective function the product of the final decision vars matrix and the zero_comp_vars and zero_cat_vars vectors.  However, getting an `Problem does not follow DCP rules` error when I do this.  Must be because of multiplying the 2 matrices by the two vectors.  Also, I wonder whether there is a way to get the program to zero out the variables in the appropriate places in the decision matrix when they don't meet the criteria for at least 2 companies and 3 categories to be non-zero in order to be included.  As it stands, the decision variables matrix will have 1s for rows/columns that are actually zeroed out by the zero_comp_vars and zero_cat_vars variables

```
util = np.array([[0.7, 0.95, 0.3], [2, 1.05, 2.2], [4, 1, 3]])

# The variable we are solving for
dec_vars = cp.Variable(util.shape, boolean = True)

zero_comp_vars = cp.Variable(util.shape[0], boolean = True)
zero_cat_vars = cp.Variable(util.shape[1], boolean = True)

# define constraints
zero_comp_constr = cp.sum(dec_vars, axis=1) >= 2 * zero_comp_vars
zero_cat_constr = cp.sum(dec_vars, axis=0) >= 3 * zero_cat_vars
# need the following two constraints, otherwise all the values in the zero_comp_constr and zero_cat_constr vectors can be 0
above_one_non_zero_comp = cp.sum(zero_comp_vars) >= 1
above_one_non_zero_cat = cp.sum(zero_cat_vars) >= 1

# min tin array
min_comp_array=np.empty(dec_vars.shape[0])
min_comp_array.fill(2)

min_comp_constr = cp.sum(dec_vars, axis=1) >= min_comp_array
tot_avg_constr = tot_util >= 2.0 * cp.sum(dec_vars)

# this is the section that gives error
temp = cp.multiply(util, dec_vars)
temp2 = cp.multiply(temp, cp.reshape(zero_comp_vars, (3,1)))
temp3 = cp.multiply(temp2, cp.reshape(zero_cat_vars, (3,1)))

tot_util = cp.sum(temp3)
#tot_util = cp.sum(cp.multiply(util, dec_vars))

cluster_problem = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(tot_util), [zero_comp_constr, zero_cat_constr, 
                                                     above_one_non_zero_comp, above_one_non_zero_cat,
                                                     min_comp_constr, tot_avg_constr])

cluster_problem.solve()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just transform it:

```
constr8 = (tot_util/cp.sum(dec_vars)) >= 1.3

->

constr8 = tot_util >= 1.3 * cp.sum(dec_vars)
```

You might need to enforce that `cp.sum(dec_vars)` is positive though or else: `0 >= 0` is a valid solution.

See also: [lpsolve docs: Ratios](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/ratio.htm)

#### Side-remark

Yes, you are targeting machine-learning scale data with general-purpose optimization tools which will quickly hit a limit, even for pure continuous cases. In your case, using discrete-optimization, you probably will run into scalability issues (sounds like 1M binary-variables), especially when limited to open-source solvers.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I move to a proprietary solver (eg. gurobi) or is there a totally different avenue that's not based on optimization?

Comment: If commercials are available (e.g. in academia) they are always the better pick. Experiment and decide yourself if IP helps for your data. As we don't know your data (statistics) and use-case, we cannot reason much about it. Customized approaches would be very costly to develop anyway, so try this first. I highly recommend generalizing your code *immediately* (no hard-coded toy-examples) such you can  scale up`N,M` towards your expected sizes with random data to see what happens (keeping in mind, that random-data behaves differently than real-world data though; in most cases).

Comment: Great, the table is sparse (half of the values are NULL), so that should help.  What is the elegant way to automate the constraint formulation?  One approach is to functionalize to write out the constraints based on loops, but that's still a bit clunky

Comment: Using loops is exactly the way. You are not that far away as you already use some algebra (generalizing well and getting rid of some loops). Not sure if flattening out early (1d decisions vars) will help you though. It's usually easier to use 2-dim and exploit axis-based sums for constraints/objectives (see `sum(dec_vars[0:3])` for some ugly effect of 1d-flattening -> you got 3 constraints which could be created by just posting something as mat-mul / row-wise expr). But that's some thing you have to try out.